# Referring files from the zip that are loaded through Spark Submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Am trying to run a Spark streaming job [Parent Job], based on some conditions another Spark submit [Child Job] is dynamically framed and submitted through the existing parent job.
The child job seems to fail with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid properties file 'filename'
```

On going through this we were able to find that the file is not present in the node where the child job is submitted. So as a work around we placed the file in HDFS and gave the location in the spark submit, still it was not able to recognize it.

```
spark-submit --name "Child_Job" --master  yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-cores 2 --driver-cores 1    --driver-memory 2g --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 1g --archives "HDFS_FILE1#FILE1,HDFS_FILE2.zip#FILE2" --properties-file "HDFS_PROPERTY_FILE" --py-files "HDFS_FILE2.zip" FILE2/Test.py
```

alternatively tried the `--archives` and `--files` still no luck, was unable to reference the files within the spark submit.

> The --files and --archives options support specifying file names with
>   the # similar to Hadoop. For example, you can specify: --files
>   localtest.txt#appSees.txt and this will upload the file you have
>   locally named localtest.txt into HDFS but this will be linked to by
>   the name appSees.txt, and your application should use the name as
>   appSees.txt to reference it when running on YARN.

Any suggestions or workaround would be really helpful, please do let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Can you try setting `--py-files` "HDFS_FILE2.zip"` somewhat to absolute path?

Comment: @karma4917 do you mean providing a local path rather than providing a HDFS path ?

Comment: Provide the complete HDFS path.

Comment: @karma4917 the Spark-Submit is done with the complete HDFS path

Comment: Hi @Joby - I'm facing similar problem. Please let me know if have any solution. Thanks